# How to submit a form using the "get" method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How do I submit a form using the "get" method to an external URL in react?

The same as this example in HTML:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method

but to a third party URL...?

I assume I can't do something like this? Aim is to output; myUrl.com/?checkin=(forminput)

```
<Form
                className='mt-2'
                layout='inline'
                method='GET'
                action='https://myURL.com'
            >
                <Form.Item label='Check in' name='checkin'>
                    <DatePicker />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button className='ml-2' onClick='submit'>
                        Search
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You set the form action to the URL in question. Do you mean via Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If the "third party URL" has CORS enabled, then it's as simple as doing a native JS `fetch`.

Example:

```
// Your CORS enabled URL
const url = "http://cors.enabled.com";

// Data to send
const data = JSON.stringify({
  fname: "John", lname: "Doe"
});

// Formulate and execute request
const response = await fetch(url, {method: "GET", body: data});
// Response JSON
const json = await response.json();

// Output response JSON
console.log({json})
```

Alternatively you could do it just the same as they suggest on the w3schools website. Using the `action` attribute. It works, but it's probably not ideal for a React app, since it will force a page change.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" target="_blank">
   [...]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by collecting the inputs into and object and send it using a library like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)  or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)